# Ubuntu server 10.04 reboots randomly

Tags: ubuntu

I have just installed ubuntu server 10.04. For few days it was going ok. But now it reboots randomly once 1-3 hours.
I have installed these packadges:
lamp, gammu-smsd, gnome-core, tightvncserver
The server is [Intel SR1625URSASR](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=48664)

Which log files I should provide?

Comment: `/var/log/messages` right around the reboot time would be an excellent start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the motherboard didn't support processors. updating bios solved that.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to doublecheck so you don't have a watchdog setup. Also /var/log/messages is a good idea, as Ignacio mentions.

Comment: I dont think that I have set up a watchdog setup. I tried to set up some monitoring apps but that was already after those random reboots.

messages.log : http://p2p.lv/messages.log (1.37 MB)
Reboot times I noticed:
17:03
17:25
18:07

Answer (score 0):

Random reboot can also mean there is a hardware problem. I had a similar case, and it finally happened to be the motherboard dying.
Did you try to inactive some components in bios to try to isolate a faulty card, or a card using a faulty bus on the motherboard ?